# How to allow to type text in raphael object, say rect?

Tags: raphael

I have created a Raphael rect like below:
`var rect1 = paper.rect(100,100,100,100)`

Now, I want that as I click on the rect a cursor appears and user is allowed to type/key in some text

I am very very new to JS and Raphael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a natural use of Raphael. Think of it primarily as a drawing library. If you look through the [SVG specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) or any of the [demos](http://raphaeljs.com/) on the RaphaelJS page, you'll get the idea.

But Raphael integrates naturally with native Javascript or jQuery. I would place a borderless textarea on top of your rectangle and activate (and focus) it when the user clicks on the space, like so:

```
var paper = Raphael("canvas", 300, 300),
    rect1 = paper.rect(100,100,100,100).attr({fill: "#FFF"});

rect1.click(function(e) {
   $('#text').show(); 
   $('#text').focus(); 
});
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NtKKZ/

(Note that you need to fill the rectangle with white in order for the click event to fire.)

Comment: *"(Note that you need to fill the rectangle with white in order for the click event to fire.)"* Filling it with "transparent" color (i.e. .attr({fill: "transparent"})) seems to work without worrying about the color of the background.