# Inline text editing in raphael js

Tags: svg, raphael, javascript

So I'm using Raphael JS and try to create user-editable text input.
What is the easiest and right way to create something like [that](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.5.1/editor/svg-editor.html) ?

Comment: You mean something like double clicking and being able to edit the text in place? That is somewhat tricky.

Comment: Duplicate of recent question. Don't use Raphael for that, use standard HTML/JS.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044337/how-to-allow-to-type-text-in-raphael-object-say-rect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a plugin for that: https://github.com/marmelab/Raphael.InlineTextEditing. As stated by Duopixel, it IS tricky to do it by hand.